# Is there known good strategy of altering primary key from int to bigint on large tables?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, rdbms

Two related tables on my production database is nearly to utilize all 32 bit of possible values for primary key. I have to migrate this key to `bigint`. Here, in other topics, I have found suggestions similar to this:

1. Drop FKs
2. Drop PK
3. Alter column `Id`
4. Alter referencing columns
5. Restore PK
6. Restore FKs

However, when I tried to perform `ALTER COLUMN Id BIGINT` on my local database with 1.5 billion rows (less then a half of rows in corresponding table on production db) - I have faced with **huge** amount of data written to log (about 800 GB, when table itself was about 50 GB after filling it with test data) after 2.5 hours of waiting operation to perform.
So I cancelled this operation, realizing this way of migration inapplicable on production DB.

It seems like migrating keys from int32 to int64 is a relatively common problem. So my question is: how do other developers and database engineers are usually dealing with it in production environments?

P.S. May be it is important that each row in tables not contains very much data.

- The first problematic table consists of 6 `int`'s (most nullable), 1 `tinyint` and 1 `datetime`. The primary key is `int`.
- The second table is just `int` column references to first table's Id, and 2 `varchar(255)`. The primary key is composite of `int` and `varchar` columns.

Comment: Is `Id` an `IDENTITY` column?

Comment: If the problem is the volume of logs, and you considered putting the database in simple recovery mode while you do the changes?

Comment: https://am2.co/2019/12/changing-a-column-from-int-to-bigint-without-downtime/

Comment: Adding to what @Larnu mentioned about simple recovery, for large tables in step 3 you could create a new table with bigint and the clustered index (which is probably the primary key but you did not include DDL). Then, load the new table using `INSERT WITH(TABLOCKX)...SELECT` for a minimally-logged operation. Then, drop the old tables, rename the new tables to the original names, and recreate constraints and non-clustered indexes.

Comment: @Larnu - isn't the table alter done in one transaction? If so, does the database being in simple recovery matter? Sure, it'll keep *other* transactions from persisting in the t-log. But for this 1.5b row table (which, if I'm reading correctly, OP did it on his local system where there *was* no other traffic), the log file needs to accommodate the entire operation, regardless of recovery model.